# How much motivation do berries restore?

Tags: pokemon-go

In order to maintain a defending Pokémon's motivation while they occupy a gym, players from that defending Pokémon's trainer's team can feed it berries. The new golden razz berry is special in that it can be used to fully replenish a defending Pokémon's motivation. What about the other berries? How much motivation does each berry restore? Does the amount differ between berries?

Comment: @Timmy Jim should probably have the accepted answer on this, as he was able to provide information on how much and the percentage drop after each usage

Comment: @Wondercricket whoops, my bad. Fixed

Comment: @Draken mentioned in the comment of the approved answer that the effect of the berries also depends whether you feed them remotely or by the gym. Asking another question about that would certainly be condemned as a duplicate of this one so please someone try to answer that part too to fully answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/gym-raid-update/gym-battle-mechanics/):

> Berries restore roughly 15-18% of your Pokémon CP on first use, similar to how much 1 lost battle reduces. After the first time you fed a Berry, diminishing returns start kicking in. Each successive Berry feeds for far less than the first one, roughly 50% less at first and that drop off continues!

The first berry will yield about 15-18% of a motivation gain, and about 50% less with each berry after that - making it more difficult to keep a Pokemon motivated.  It should be noted though that this is for if you are feeding them berries rapidly.  Niantic George on Reddit stated:

> You can give Berries to any Pokémon on Gyms controlled by your team at any time. There are some **significant diminishing returns if you feed the same Pokémon multiple Berries over a short period of time**.

As noted on many sites ([Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/gym-raid-update/golden-razz-berry/) for example), the Golden Razz Berry will restore 100% motivation:

> Pokémon GO Golden Razz Berry is a special variant of the commonly known Razz Berry. It can be used for two purposes: **fully restoring a Gym Defender’s motivation meter** and drastically increasing your chance to capture a wild Pokémon.

Comment: There's also a difference if you feed your Pokémon when at the gym or remotely, do you have the stats on that?

Comment: @Draken The question was asked prior to the ability to feed berries remotely, which is why it wasn’t included in the answer. But from personal experience, it is *significantly* lower - only increasing my Pokémon’s CP anywhere between 80 - 120 on the first one

Answer (score 9):

While it will require more testing to know how much motivation berries will restore, it is stated on [this article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-what-is-motivation-meter-how-to-restore/) that a Razz Berry, Pinap Berry, and Nanab Berry restore the motivation in equal amounts. As you already mentioned, the Golden Razz Berry fully restores the motivation

> However, it’s possible to replenish the motivation of one of your Pokemon. All you have to do is feed it berries. Any kind of berries are acceptable, so you can give it Razz Berries, Nanab Berries, or Pinap Berries. **All three of those provide the Pokemon with the exact same amount of motivation**, although a step above them is the Golden Razz Berry, as that one fully restores the motivation bar

Also, according to [this article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-what-do-the-hearts-above-a-pokemon-indicate/), the amount of motivation each berry restores decreases every time you use one to prevent a player from spamming berries to reach 100% motivation

> If you want to fully restore your Pokemon’s motivation, though, you can’t just continuously feed it berries. That’s because when you feed a Pokemon multiple berries in a row, the berries provide the Pokemon with less and less motivation. This discourages players from simply visiting their gym over and over again and constantly keeping their Pokemon at high motivations so that no one can take the gym down. It also encourages cooperation, as although you can’t replenish a Pokemon by giving it many berries in a row, one of your teammates can give it a second berry which will provide just as much motivation as the first one you gave it.